# php: display each element of an array as a string

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

hi guys its my first day with php. i guess this is an easy one for you. can someone help me to display each element of  my array $result[] as a string in $result_device[]?

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "db");      

    $sql = "SELECT erker, brunnen, stehlampe, computer, mediacenter FROM 
    devices";
    if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
        echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
        echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
        exit;
    }

  $result = $result->fetch_row();
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($result as list ($result_device)) {
    if ($result_device[i]==0){
      $result_device[i] = "ausgeschaltet";
      }
    elseif ($result_device[i]==1){
      $result_device[i] = "eingeschaltet";
      }
      $i++;

  }
  echo $result_device[0];
  echo $result_device[1];
  echo $result_device[2];
  echo $result_device[3];
  echo $result_device[4];


  $result->close();
  $mysqli->close();
  ?>
```

thank you very much!

Comment: First print your result in side the foreach. 
print_r($result_device) and  check your array and add your array here

Comment: You used a foreach loop just a few lines above. Have a look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and i think you will sort it out.

Comment: This doesn't seem right `$result = $result->fetch_row();` Do you really want to over-write the object?

Comment: `i` is not going to use the declared `$i` value.  In fact, you don't need to use a counter (`$i`) if you are just generating an indexed array.  You can push values into your result array, by using `$result_device[]='whatever';`  What coding tutorials did you read to arrive at this code?

Comment: it`s okay for me to overwrite $result, then i don`t need another variable i guess
or?

Comment: Check the manual, your code can be improved simply by implementing the demo snippet. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: it`s not working when i print_r($result_device) in the foreach loop. it doesnt display anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to improve your code like below:-

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "db");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result_device = [];
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT erker, brunnen, stehlampe, computer, mediacenter FROM devices")) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
       print_r($row); 
       // Based on oputput modify condition and assign values to $result_device
    }

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: ok thank you very much!. im trying to understand and i go on from there!

Comment: i spent some time with it but finally it works. thanks for your help

Comment: @KaiH.  glad to help you and it's really good that you tried yourself.That's how you will learn